# Traversing through tree structure using mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, tree, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb and trying aggregation. I need help for the following problem. 
I have a collection like this

```
{_id: 1,  parentId: null, name: 'foo'},
{_id: 2,  parentId: '1', name: 'boo'},
{_id: 3,  parentId: '2', name: 'koo'},
{_id: 4,  parentId: '3', name: 'coo'}
{_id: 5,  parentId: '4', name: 'loo'}
```

I would like to perform aggregation and get list of parents and children of an id. How can I achieve this ? thanks in advance.

I tried graphLookup of mongodb, but not getting result as expected. I tried this.

```
    db.files.aggregate([ { $graphLookup: {
     from : 'files',
     startWith: '$id',
     connectFromField: 'parentId',
     connectToField: 'id',
     as: 'parents'
}}])
```

output format I required is:

```
{
id: id,
parents: [{id, name}],
children: []
}
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/

Comment: What exactly is the JSON output you would want to receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've changed your `parentId` fields to be integers, too, in order to match the `_id` fields you can do this:

```
db.files.aggregate([{
    $graphLookup: {
        from : 'files',
        startWith: '$parentId',
        connectFromField: 'parentId',
        connectToField: '_id',
        as: 'parents'
    }
}, {
    $graphLookup: {
        from : 'files',
        startWith: '$_id',
        connectFromField: '_id',
        connectToField: 'parentId',
        as: 'children'
    }
}])
```

Based on your comment it would appear like you would want to add a `$match` stage at the start to query for a specific `_id` and a `$project` stage at the end to trim the output to what is required:

```
db.files.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        _id: 3
    }
}, {
    $graphLookup: {
        from : 'files',
        startWith: '$parentId',
        connectFromField: 'parentId',
        connectToField: '_id',
        as: 'parents'
    }
}, {
    $graphLookup: {
        from : 'files',
        startWith: '$_id',
        connectFromField: '_id',
        connectToField: 'parentId',
        as: 'children'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "parents._id": 1,
        "parents.name": 1,
        "children": 1,
    }
}])
```

Comment: Hy @dnickless, thanks for prompt response. I need to query against an id and get the required output with list of parents and children.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dnickless. It helped me. Of course i am doing some modifications. I am accepting the answer.